# Wakelock implementation in a service

Tags: android, wakelock, commonsware-cwac

I have a service that executes in 2 phones. They communicate with each other using sockets and execute some script (which may take 1-2 minutes approx.) and exchange files (using HTTP Post) between them.

I want this execution to continue, even when the screen is off, i.e acquire a Wakelock. I saw [this link](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful), but I'm not sure where to incorporate this in my code(as the device may sleep in the mid of execution). Any guidance is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: "They communicate with each other using sockets and execute some script (which may take 1-2 minutes approx.) and exchange files (using HTTP Post) between them." -- and what is the trigger mechanism for this work?

Comment: I m using same app for 2 phones. In onCreate() it starts a service listening on a port. Clicking a button in phone1, does a HTTP Post of a file to phone2 and the communication keeps going on(as phone 2 also listens on a port initially). @CommonsWare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I m using same app for 2 phones. In onCreate() it starts a service listening on a port. Clicking a button in phone1, does a HTTP Post of a file to phone2 and the communication keeps going on(as phone 2 also listens on a port initially).

Well, your primary objective seems to be to cause the owner of phone2 to attack you with a scimitar, since the phone2 will run out of battery.

That being said, your HTTP daemon will need to be in a service, where you acquire and release a `WakeLock` (and presumably a `WifiLock`, since what you want won't work over most mobile data connections).

`WakefulIntentService` is not useful here, because it is designed for sensible scenarios, where we need to keep a `WakeLock` acquired only for a brief period of time, to complete some specific task. In your case, you need to keep your `WakeLock` acquired indefinitely, as you have no idea when work might need to be done.

> I m not sure where to incorporate this in my code.

In the service, presumably. You will probably acquire the `WakeLock` in `onCreate()` of the service and release it in `onDestroy()` of the service. If you wish to avoid a scimitar-related demise, you will make sure that the user has plenty of control over exactly when this service is running, and therefore have plenty of control over when this `WakeLock` is in force.

Comment: I have added the wake lock and wi-fi locks. My service starts executing after some time(say 5 minutes) after the screen is locked(When I view the logs in Logcat). I ve acquired a partial wakelock. Is this an expected behavior? @CommonsWare

Comment: @user1741274: "Is this an expected behavior?" -- I have no idea, as I did not write your code.

Comment: Sorry. I have acquired a partial wake lock. I meant to ask: there is a time variation between execution of task each time after I lock my screen i.e, sometimes task executes after 5 minutes or sometimes after 10 minutes(after I lock the screen). Any idea as to why it varies? @CommonsWare

Comment: @user1741274: "Any idea as to why it varies?" -- I have no idea, as I did not write your code. I do not know what is triggering the "task" to "execute", and hence I have no idea why anything might affect that.

Comment: I have implemented WakeLock(using PowerManager), acquired when the service starts and released when the service ends. I want to monitor battery consumption. While testing, I notice that when the device is plugged in, it seem to work fine. When it is disconnected, the service seems to stop. Is this expected behavior? Please guide me. @CommonsWare

Answer (score 1):

Why not implement that functionality with a service? See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). I'm not very experienced in android development but have worked recently in a project where a functionality similar to that was implemented using services.

Comment: Yes I m implementing as a service(which starts on click of a button in UI). Please see line 1 @rmcc

Comment: So, I'm not understanding correctly what is the problem. If you have a service, why shoud it not continue working when the screen is off?

Comment: In phone 1, my service starts, calls an intent(that executes some script in a file) and notifies after completion using Broadcast. In onReceive() method defined in the service, I am posting the updated file to II phone and it goes on. @rmcc

Comment: In here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html a very good documentation for services, as you probably know. I'm not fully understanding what is the real problem. As you can see in the beginning of the document it has a description of what a started service is that seems what you are trying to accomplish. Also take a look at Running a Service in the Foreground.

Comment: When I run my app, when the screen goes off, the application stops. So I need a Wake-Lock for this. I m not sure where to incorporate this in my code. @rmcc

Comment: If you are running a service, that shouldn't happen. Maybe there's something wrong with your service's implementation. I happen to be working on an application that if a determined event happens the service has to warn the user. It's fully implemented with a service and works fine.

Comment: Hello again. I wasn't quite sure about what the problem was until I reproduced it. I got around the same problem when I implemented a service that was reading values from the accelerometer. When the screen is locked/goes off the system goes into power saving mode and disables some services. Sensor service is one of them and as I checked around your problem also happens. The way I worked around this was by acquiring a wakelock on onCreate and disabling when not not needed. In your case you can acquire it the transfer starts and release it when it's over.

Comment: You can use the link that is given in the question for implementation. Ya in my case, I have implemented already :)

Comment: I solved it on my end. The only problem is the battery consumption. It goes through the roof if you try to get a continuous reading of accelerometer values.