# Android Wakelock not working when screen is off

Tags: android, service, wakelock

I m trying to implement wake lock and wifi lock for  a service. More about my scenario in this like: [Wakelock implementation in a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13359111/wakelock-implementation-in-a-service). I m acquiring during start and releasing when the service gets destroyed. I want to monitor the battery consumption for my project, though I understand that, this approach is not good. But when my phone screen is off, it is not working. I have enabled the option: Keep Wifi on during sleep. As soon as my screen turns off, my service stops.I m using the snippet :

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Lock");
if(!wakeLock.isHeld())
{
wakeLock.acquire();
}
Log.d(TAG,"Acquired Wake lock successfully");
wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiLock = wifiManager.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF , "WiFi LockTag");
if(!wifiLock.isHeld())
{
wifiLock.acquire();
}
Log.d(TAG,"Acquired Wifi lock successfully");
```

//TO RELEASE

```
try{
wifiLock.release(); 
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
Log.d(TAG,"Exception while releasing WakeLock :: Can be ignoredd");
}
```

Any idea of why this is happening ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have a device which does some UPNP network activity. Even when I hold a Partial Wake Lock, and Wifi Lock, when screen is off, UPNP is unreliable. When screen is on, UPNP is fine. Some devices perhaps don't honour the wake lock?

Answer (score 0):

to protect screen from being lock use this Spinet

```
public static void unlockTheScreen(Context context) {
    KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
    KeyguardLock keyguardLock =  keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock("TAG");
    keyguardLock.disableKeyguard();     
}
```

Add below in your wake lock

```
  wakeLock = powermanager.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP ), "TAG");
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. When I use partial wakelock, the CPU is on and screen is off.This consumes less power than having a full_wakelock. Isnt so? @Usman Kurd